# Python plotly logo disapering from chart

Tags: python, plotly

I have to create a simple report that show one data table and have two logos in the top corners. The code below worked in a previous project but now that I’m reusing it on a new computer for a new project it wont show the logos.

I get no error message. Same version of plotly and python "plotly==4.6.0" "Python 3.6.1"

Please note that the only thing that changed is the data shown in the datatable.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd



traces = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
            align='left'),
    cells=dict(
        values=df.T.values.tolist(),
        align='left'))



layout = go.Layout(
                title='Report <br>  {}'.format( report_date),
                title_x=0.5,
                paper_bgcolor='#FFFFFF',
                margin = {'t':100, 'b':40, 'r':40, 'l':40}
                ,images=[
                    dict(
                        source='assets\\MiniLogo.png',
                        xref='paper',yref='paper',
                        x=1,y=1.05,
                        sizex=0.2, sizey=0.2,
                        xanchor="right", yanchor="bottom"), 
                    dict(
                        source='assets\\Titlelogo.png',
                        xref='paper',yref='paper',
                        x=0,y=1.05,
                        sizex=0.2, sizey=0.2,
                        xanchor="left", yanchor="bottom")

                    ]

                )
fig = go.Figure(
        data=traces
        ,layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Thats the thing, I dont get any error message, it just generates the figure with everything besides the two logos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is within the `source` argument in your `layout`. I've used your code with [this image URL](https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png) instead of a relative path and it works perfectly and here is a screenshot knowing that I've used a simple table as my `df`:

[image]

In my opinion, you have two options to overcome that:

- Upload these images to a cloud-service and use their URLs instead.
- Or according to this [Plolty community thread](https://community.plotly.com/t/using-local-image-as-background-image/4381/4), you can use `Pillow.Image` class to read the image from your local machine. You can install it easily by running `pip install pillow` and modify your code to be like so:

  ```
  from PIL import Image

  layout= go.Layout(images= [dict(
                    source= Image.open('assets\\MiniLogo.png'),
                    ...)])
  ```

Comment: Thanks! The addition of PIL Image helped.

Comment: Glad I could help!!